# C++ Friend function cannot access private memeber; error 2248

Tags: c++, private-members, friend-function

For homework I have to create a class with some private members of bool type. A friend function has to be created that will take two parameters: pointer to object and pointer to a object's private member.
The code is defined as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

class SomeClass {
    friend int FriendFunction(bool SomeClass::*privMember, SomeClass *object);
private:
    bool Member1;
    bool Member2;
    bool Member3;
public:
    SomeClass() {
        bool tmp;

        if (rand()  < 16384)
            tmp = false;
        else
            tmp = true;
        Member1 = tmp;

        if (rand()  < 16384)
            tmp = false;
        else
            tmp = true;
        Member2 = tmp;

        if (rand()  < 16384)
            tmp = false;
        else
            tmp = true;
        Member3 = tmp;
    }
};

int FriendFunction(bool SomeClass::*privMember, SomeClass *object) {
    if (!(object->*privMember))
        object->*privMember = !(object->*privMember);
    else
        cout << "No changes made" << endl;
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    SomeClass *object1 = new SomeClass();

    FriendFunction(&SomeClass::Member1, object1);
    FriendFunction(&SomeClass::Member2, object1);
    FriendFunction(&SomeClass::Member3, object1);

    return 0;

}
```

The FriendFunction calls do not compile and compiler reports C2248 message.
What is wrong with the code?
I would appreciate any support.

Thanks

Comment: I bet that the compiler errors are in the `main` function where you actually access the private members.

Comment: If you have the freedom (in the context of your task) to define getter functions, then you can easily get access to pointers to your class's private members. Then you can use your _FriendFunction_ .

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are trying to access the private members from `main`:

```
FriendFunction(&SomeClass::Member1, object1);
```

This line is referring the private field `&SomeClass::Member1` from `main`, and, of course, fails.

Comment: This indeed is the cause of the problem. Declaring `int main()` as a friend to SomeClass compiles the code, but this is of course only the method to prove where the problem lies. The question still remains: how can I pass the pointer to a private class member to the FriendFunction?

Comment: @Marko, in your specific case I would store the variables in an array, and pass an index in that array instead of a pointer to member.

Comment: I am aware that the passing the index is one of the solution but unfortunately this is not really giving the solution to my homework task. What is defined in the task is definition of private class members of type bool, a friend function with two arguments (pointer to object and pointer to object's private member) that needs to change a private member to the value true in case the constructor set it to false. Could it even be done in the way the task requires?